# How do you get a double line 'text art' to display horizontally multiple times instead of vertically?

Tags: java

I don't know how to put it into words.. but basically lets say I have this code:

```
while (count <= getCherryLeft()) {
System.out.println(" I ");
System.out.println(" O ");
count++;
}
```

The output looks like this :

```
   I
   O
   I
   O
   I
   O
```

etc...

But I actually want it to look like this:

```
 I I I
 O O O
```

Does this make sense? I'm sorry if it sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the output you want, you should write two `while` loops,

```
while (count <= getCherryLeft()) {
    System.out.print(" I ");
    count++;
}

System.out.println("");

while (count <= getCherryLeft()) {
    System.out.print(" O ");
    count++;
}
```

The first while loop will print the `I` and second will print `O`

Comment: Thank you! But why is my output only showing I I I and not the O O O? EDIT : NVM SOLVED!

Comment: @Xirol are you getting any problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    StringBuilder lineOne = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder lineTwo = new StringBuilder();
    while (count <= getCherryLeft()) {
        lineOne.append(" I ");
        lineTwo.append(" O ");
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(lineOne.toString());
    System.out.println(lineTwo.toString());
```